# ORB in python binding of OpenCV 2.4.0

Tags: python, opencv

Has ORB feature detector been ported to the python bindings of OpenCV 2.4.0 ? If so how can i use it ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think not implemented. Check out it in http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html?highlight=orb#ORB : public Feature2D

Comment: I posted an answer which might also be helpful here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/15099494/594925

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample script called "feature_homography.py" that uses ORB features.  You can checkout the samples directory.

```
svn co http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/tags/2.4.1/opencv/samples
```

From the sample:

```
detector = cv2.FastFeatureDetector(16, True)
detector = cv2.GridAdaptedFeatureDetector(detector)
extractor = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create('ORB')
```